# calling a web service in Talend tRestClient

Tags: talend

How to call a Rest Web service using tRestClient with a POST method and pass a json.
I've viewed the documentation of Talend but nothing about POST method and how to pass the json to the tRestClient.
any help please?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to set the **HTTP Method** to POST.

Then, a new field opens up, **HTTP Body**. Your JSON body could look like this:

```
"{
    \"MyRequestParameter1\":\"abc\",
    \"ANumberParameter\":\"456\"
}"
```

Just make sure all quotes in the JSON are escaped properly.

Comment: thanks for the reply,, and then get the responce in tFileOutputJson?
I've did that but it returns null body responce

Comment: To process the data you can use the **tExtractJSONFields** component. Also to check the body response use **tLogRow**.

Comment: Did anyone get to work this out? I am stuck at the exact same point. Can get the GET working but the POST is where I've hit an impasse. Just don't know how to pass on the JSON data to the REST endpoint.

@os.Kh

Comment: @tobi6 Could you please offer some help?